# Work Order Status Change - Triggering Script when Work Order is created due to 'Special Order Item'

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I'm having an issue where I have released a beforeSubmit UserEvent script that automatically changes the work order status to 'Released' based on criteria I have chosen (specifically that the work order is related to a specific customer/entity).

The script changes the work order to released (as expected) when:

- I create a work order from scratch and select the customer
- have a work order that is created from a sales order (ie the netsuite 'special work order item' functionality) and go into the the planned order and edit/save.

However I want this to work when the work order is automatically created from the sales order, using the NS 'special work order item' functionality.

I dont believe the issue is the code itself - I think it has something to do with the 'special work order item' and possibly the context settings on my deployment. Right now I have the 'event type' set to All and context filtering set to ALL.

Has anyone run into this issue?

My other thought is I coud probably run a scheduled script that sets these types of work orders to released but ideally would like to go the userevent route first.

Comment: can you post your code? Does your code test the context.type value? If you are checking that the type is 'create'  you may also need to also check type 'specialorder', This is not an answer because I've had this issue on special order POs but haven't dealt with it on work orders.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the `After Record Submit` function and it worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).